# How does Firefox link these files on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, ntfs

I'm using Windows 10 and Firefox 66.

If I use Firefox's "Save Page As..." (ctrl + s) to downlaod a webpage that has more than simple text (i.e., js, css, images etc.), I get a `webpage.htm` file as well as a folder called `webpage_data` containing the extra resources. In Windows explorer, these look like normal files and folders -- no icon overlays or anything indicating that they behave differently from any other file or folder.

However, If I delete the folder, the file gets deleted as well!

I've never seen files "linked" like this in a Windows filesystem before. What's going on here? Is this something I can replicate with arbitrary files and folders via the file properties dialog?

Comment: Short answer: `.htm` and `.html` files are linked with their correspondingly named folders containing resources, with the folder name itself ending in `_file(s)`. This cannot be replicated except by (re)naming an arbitrary file with the `.htm(l)` extension and then creating an appropriately named folder.

Comment: @Anaksunaman interesting, thanks. seems weird to me that microsoft would put such non-obvious behavior in the shell for such an obscure edge-case. shrug.